# Using Params with API calls via a GET request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ruby-on-rails-4

I am developing an api for an iOS application. I currently have a Property class that has many Issues. In the API controller for Index I have the following code:

```
def index
    @issues = @property.issues
end
```

I am setting the `@property` var with a before_action

I currently have this in my routes file inside my API wrapper routes:

```
  resources :issues do 
    resources :comments
  end
```

It is obviously putting the proper REST verbs for to the calls, but my issue is I am in need of passing the parameter of property_id in order for my before action to find `Property.where(id: pay ams[:property_id]`.

1. Can I pass parameters at all during a GET request to rails 4.
2. Do I need to do it in the URL with `?property_id=1` or in the request header?
3. Do I need to specify parameters in the routes file for this GET request?
4. In Rails 4, would the strong parameters take place and I need to pass a body of:

   ```
   {
    "issue":["property_id":2]
   }
   ```

Comment: There is no strong parameter restrictions here, I'm assuming thats only on the POST methods when interacting with AR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes you can pass on parameters to GET requests
2. Do it with ?pid=4
3. No, you dont have to specify it in routes.
4. Not clear.